# What function do I use to store a single character in a cin statement so that I can process each character individually?

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that is suppose to ask the user to enter a word and then translate it in CIAO. However, when my program compiles, it only processes the first letter into my switch statement the number of times the word's length is. What function do I use?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()                                                                  
{                                                                           
    //Identify Variables                                                    
    string word;                                                            
    int counter;                                                            
    char letters, word1, word3;                                             

    //Ask user to input a word to be translated into I.C.A.O                
    cout<<" Enter a word: ";                                                
    cin>>word;                                                              

    counter = word.length(); //Counts the number of characters the user inputed
    word1 = word[0]; //Converts a string to a char value                 

    //Use a while statement to repeat until there are zero letters to process
    while(counter != 0)                                                     
    {                                                                       
        //Use a switch statement to translate each letter into I.C.A.O      
        switch(word1)                                                       
        {                                                                   
            case 'a': case 'A': cout<<"Alpha\n"; break;                     
            case 'b': case 'B': cout<<"Bravo\n"; break;                     
            case 'c': case 'C': cout<<"Charlie\n"; break;                   
            case 'd': case 'D': cout<<"Delta\n"; break;                     
            case 'e': case 'E': cout<<"Echo\n"; break;                      
            case 'f': case 'F': cout<<"Foxtrot\n"; break;                   
            case 'g': case 'G': cout<<"Golf\n"; break;                      
            case 'h': case 'H': cout<<"Hotel\n"; break;                     
            case 'i': case 'I': cout<<"India\n"; break;                     
            case 'j': case 'J': cout<<"Juliet\n"; break;                    
            case 'k': case 'K': cout<<"Kilo\n"; break;                      
            case 'l': case 'L': cout<<"Lima\n"; break;                      
            case 'm': case 'M': cout<<"Mike\n"; break;                      
            case 'n': case 'N': cout<<"November\n"; break;                  
            case 'o': case 'O': cout<<"Oscar\n"; break;                     
            case 'p': case 'P': cout<<"Papa\n"; break;                      
            case 'q': case 'Q': cout<<"Quebec\n"; break;                    
            case 'r': case 'R': cout<<"Romeo\n"; break;                     
            case 's': case 'S': cout<<"Sierra\n"; break;                    
            case 't': case 'T': cout<<"Tango\n"; break;                     
            case 'u': case 'U': cout<<"Uniform\n"; break;                   
            case 'v': case 'V': cout<<"Victor\n"; break;                    
            case 'w': case 'W': cout<<"Whiskey\n"; break;                   
            case 'x': case 'X': cout<<"X-Ray\n"; break;                     
            case 'y': case 'Y': cout<<"Yankee\n"; break;                    
            case 'z': case 'Z': cout<<"Zulu\n"; break;                      
        }                                                                   

        counter--;                                                          
    }                                                                       

    return 0;                                                               
}
```

Comment: You never modify `word1`.  What do you expect to happen inside that loop?

Comment: Kudos for using the correct phonetic alphabet.

Comment: Why not `for (size_t counter = 0; counter < word.length(); counter++) { switch (word[counter]) { ... }`? Or even C++ better `for (auto a : word) { switch (a) {...}`?

Comment: I had to convert the string word into a char so that it could work in a switch statement. But that is not the issue, the issue is that I don't know what function to use to process each letter individually in my switch statement.

Comment: Where would I put that for statement exactly?

Comment: You replace your `while(counter != 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are truly limited to nothing but `#include <iostream>`, then you cannot use `string` (requires `#include <string>`) and you are stuck using the good old character array. In this case that isn't a draw-back, it's actually easier.

You don't want to use *magic-numbers* so declare a constant of sufficient size to for sizing your array to allow you to read words without running out of space. The longest word in the non-medical Unabridged Dictionary is 29-characters (so `+1` for the *nul-terminating* character would require 30-characters total). Since you *Never Skimp On Buffer Size!*, `256` will suffice, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 256
...
    char word[MAXC];
```

Now all you do is read from `stdin` into `word` with your `cin >> word`. However, you really should *Validate* the read succeeds and the user didn't cancel with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze), e.g.

```
    //Ask user to input a word to be translated into I.C.A.O
    cout << " Enter a word: ";
    if (!(cin >> word)) {
        cerr << "(user canceled input)\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

Now just loop over the characters in `word`. You can use a pointer or a `for` loop and array indexing, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; word[i]; i++)
    {
        //Use a switch statement to translate each letter into I.C.A.O
        switch (word[i])
        {
            case 'a': case 'A': cout<<"Alpha\n"; break;
            case 'b': case 'B': cout<<"Bravo\n"; break;
            case 'c': case 'C': cout<<"Charlie\n"; break;
            ...
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include<iostream>

#define MAXC 256

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    //Identify Variables
    char word[MAXC];
    int i;

    //Ask user to input a word to be translated into I.C.A.O
    cout << " Enter a word: ";
    if (!(cin >> word)) {
        cerr << "(user canceled input)\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* Use a for loop to iterate over each character in word */
    for (i = 0; word[i]; i++)
    {
        //Use a switch statement to translate each letter into I.C.A.O
        switch (word[i])
        {
            case 'a': case 'A': cout<<"Alpha\n"; break;
            case 'b': case 'B': cout<<"Bravo\n"; break;
            case 'c': case 'C': cout<<"Charlie\n"; break;
            case 'd': case 'D': cout<<"Delta\n"; break;
            case 'e': case 'E': cout<<"Echo\n"; break;
            case 'f': case 'F': cout<<"Foxtrot\n"; break;
            case 'g': case 'G': cout<<"Golf\n"; break;
            case 'h': case 'H': cout<<"Hotel\n"; break;
            case 'i': case 'I': cout<<"India\n"; break;
            case 'j': case 'J': cout<<"Juliet\n"; break;
            case 'k': case 'K': cout<<"Kilo\n"; break;
            case 'l': case 'L': cout<<"Lima\n"; break;
            case 'm': case 'M': cout<<"Mike\n"; break;
            case 'n': case 'N': cout<<"November\n"; break;
            case 'o': case 'O': cout<<"Oscar\n"; break;
            case 'p': case 'P': cout<<"Papa\n"; break;
            case 'q': case 'Q': cout<<"Quebec\n"; break;
            case 'r': case 'R': cout<<"Romeo\n"; break;
            case 's': case 'S': cout<<"Sierra\n"; break;
            case 't': case 'T': cout<<"Tango\n"; break;
            case 'u': case 'U': cout<<"Uniform\n"; break;
            case 'v': case 'V': cout<<"Victor\n"; break;
            case 'w': case 'W': cout<<"Whiskey\n"; break;
            case 'x': case 'X': cout<<"X-Ray\n"; break;
            case 'y': case 'Y': cout<<"Yankee\n"; break;
            case 'z': case 'Z': cout<<"Zulu\n"; break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/char_switch
 Enter a word: abcdefg
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
Golf
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any additional questions.

**With `#include <string>` Allowed**

The code can be virtually identical using `string word` instead of `char word[256]`. The only changes that are required are to *delete* the line `#define MAXC 256` and then:

```
#include <string>
...
    string word;
```

The remainder of the code can be exactly the same because you can index a C++ `string` in the same manner you index a C character array. You also have all the other form of the C++ loop available that we discussed at length in the comments. If you want examples of using them, I'm happy to add them, let me know.

However, you should probably use a proper `string::iterator` to loop over the characters from `word.begin()` to the character before `word.end()` which is just another way of doing the same thing. Here that would be:

```
    for (string::iterator c = word.begin(); c != word.end(); c++) 
    {
        //Use a switch statement to translate each letter into I.C.A.O
        switch (*c)
        {
            case 'a': case 'A': cout<<"Alpha\n"; break;
            case 'b': case 'B': cout<<"Bravo\n"; break;
            case 'c': case 'C': cout<<"Charlie\n"; break;
            ...
```

An iterator is actually a pointer to the member of the container (the character in `word` for your `string`), so that is why you use the dereference `*c` in `switch (*c)` to pass the thing pointed to by the iterator (the character) instead of the iterator itself (a pointer to that character).

(don't forget to delete the `int i;` declaration if you go this route -- it's no longer needed)

Comment: Thank you! It works, however I can use <string> and I was wondering if you could show me it that way and explan it in more detail.

Comment: Sure, I'll drop an addition.

Comment: When using `operator>>` to read into a `char[]` array, you should use `std::setw()` to ensure `operator>>` does not exceed the bounds of the array. Otherwise, use `std::cin.get()` instead, which has an overload for reading into a `char` buffer with size checking

Answer (score 2):

You never modify `word1` in your loop, so the switch statement will always select the letter first letter, which you initialized it to prior to the loop.

The correct way to do this is by looping through the characters in the word like this:

```
for (char c : word)
{                                                                       
    switch (c) {
        //...
    }
}
```

If you are using a compiler that doesn't support C++11 features such as range-based loops (used above), you can go oldskool:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
    switch(word[i]) ...
}
```

Or:

```
for (std::string::const_iterator it = word.cbegin(); it != word.cend(); it++) {
    switch(*it) ...
}
```

Comment: for (char c: word) is not a way to properly format a for statement. So I'm not sure what you are saying here. for(initialization ;test;update)                                                           
                                      {statement}                                                is the proper way.

Comment: Thanks, but aren't you the one here who is asking for expert advice?  Read the answer.

Comment: @KoolKassia ..chuckling... `for (auto var : object)` is a *range-based* `for` loop introduced in C++11. If you don't specify `-std=c++11` (and if your compiler doesn't provide it as an extension) -- you won't be able to use it.

Comment: I am, I am just saying that I tested it, and that my compiler told me that it was an improper formatting.

Comment: So in that case, read the second and third code examples to compensate for your outdated compiler.

Comment: I am not suppose to use anything in this program except anything found in <iostream>. Sense I am only a beginner. This is for a hw assignment and if I use that my teacher won't be too happy.

Comment: [Range-based for loop (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) If you are using an older compiler, then of course it will scold you for trying to use it `:)` It is a language built-in -- a different type of `for` loop (the old ones are still there) -- you don't need any header to use it.

Comment: `std::string` is not found in `<iostream>` so you may have to rethink your design.

Comment: Surely @KoolKassia can use `#include <string>` -- if not, you are stuck with a good old character array (e.g. `char word[256];`) -- which actually makes things easier, then you can just declare `char *p = word;` and your loop becomes `for (; *p; p++) { switch (*p) { ... }}` or `int i; for (i=0; word[i]; i++) { switch (word[i]) { ... }}`

Comment: Yes, I was being facetious.  The point is that this is simply a loop that indexes into `std::string` using either straight indexing or iterators (which are part of `std::string` anyway).  Regarding char arrays, I would be seriously disappointed if that's what the teacher is trying to promote.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I think I recongnize std:: but I'm not sure how to use it, also I might have to make a program with an array possibly. But my teacher told us about it but it's not in my textbook

Comment: I always fully-qualify stuff from the `std` namespace.  You're not doing that because for some reason beginners are still taught the awful practice of `using namespace std;`.  I could have omitted it to stick with the style of your question, but it actually takes more effort to defeat my muscle memory and omit it than it does to type it in.  Plus, you get to learn something.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the middle code example.  It's exactly what you were trying to do, but you just didn't know how to do it.  If you use the last one, your teacher will probably know that you got your answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I used the middle one and my program closes when it starts because there is no statement that would allow it to enter the loop. If you read my code you can see that I said as long as counter !=0 is the statement.

Comment: I guess what I need is to find a way to convert a string to a char because I need a string to determine the number of characters in the word and then convert it to a char to use in a switch statement.

Comment: Regarding your program "closing when it starts", that sounds absurd and I can't even imagine how you chose to interpret my answer.  But okay.  As for the restrictions, you should have mentioned them in the first place in your question.  Your teacher should also consider dropping the pretense and teach C instead, since they appear to be strictly against teaching modern C++.